# How to create two columns , three columns & two column in same table?

Tags: html, css, email, templates

[image]

I would like to create a table as shown below for an email template.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: We are glad to help you, but first you have to try to code your own solution, and post here your attemps. Please read [mcve]

Comment: Have a look at using colspan and have the total number of columns divisible by both 3 and 2 (eg 6 columns in total)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the markup

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content</td>
                    <td>Content</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
           <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content</td>
                    <td>Content</td>
                    <td>Content</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content</td>
                    <td>Content</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the title asks for it in the same table